# Is it possible to split a HTML <table>'s rows using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to make a table row appear on two different visually using CSS?

e.g.:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...displayed as:

```
___________
| A1      |
| A2 | A3 |
-----------
| B1      |
| B2 | B3 |
-----------
```

Comment: ...why? You're trying to twist a table into a not-table. Even if you somehow managed to make this happen, it'd be easier to just re-code it with markup that's actually amenable to being styled this way. Or just put those first cels into their own rows, with the td spanned across.

Comment: @Su' very defeatist - surely that's like telling me to use tables instead of divs if I want something to be styled like a table?

Comment: There's nothing defeatist in pointing out that you provided no context for wanting to do something that on the surface just looks wrong. There's now a bit more in response to Marcin below, but it doesn't change my opinion you'd probably be better off with another approach.

Comment: I have a similar problem in that I want to split the table row if it gets too long, but I don't know in advance how long it will be.  I think comments like "why would you want to do that" are out of place.  There is frequently some good reason.

Comment: While not directly answering your question, I would suggest you use a list format instead. It organises your data in a way sympathetic to screen readers, and is easy to lay out in practically any format (including tabularly) via CSS. Lists are also easier to handle for responsive layouts than tables, should that be a concern. If you find you are jumping through hoops with CSS, chances are your structure itself could be improved.

Comment: The fact is, his choice to use a table or not depends exclusively on whether the data is intended to be relational, or tabular. It's a semantics issue that he apparently has already solved. He's asking for the means to style it to his preferences. Whether you *like* his aesthetic preferences is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a very old question, but the basic idea was on larger screens to display a normal table, and on smaller ones to wrap stuff.  E.g. 1st column could be "Name", 2nd col "Age", 3rd col "favorite color".  Makes sense to me in constrained space to move the identifying data above the rest, but in larger space to display as normal columns on a single row.

Comment: lol I didn't realize how old this was... I even posted some rambling as an 'answer' below. Hope you ended up solving this.

Comment: Well, to start off one might set all td's to display block with a fixed width and float: left. The issue however is, that then you get like this: A1 A2 <break> A3 <break> B1 B2 <break> B3

Comment: Here is a nice list of techniques for twisting tables into mobile friendly layouts with only CSS: <http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/> *The comparision/roundup is done by Chris Coyier.* Currently, I do not think that there is one good solution, but that article may help get future people going.

Answer (score 2):

The structure you show in your ascii art is not really a table in the normal sense - you might  as well just use a structure of nested divs.

If you insist on doing this with a table, you might change the `display` and `position` model of your A1/B1 cells, and set a fixed width of table and cells, then move the A1/B1 cells.

Comment: "you might as well just use a structure of nested divs" - no, it's still, semantically, tabulated data - it's just that in some circumstances we lack the space to display full rows without them looking stupid.  Will give the `display` and `position` vars a tweak and see where I get - thanks for the pointers.

Comment: A scenario where this would come into play is a 4x4 table on desktop then on mobile you want it a 2x8 table. While it's tabular data you still want it to display nicely thus breaking it up at a specific media point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hack around with `display: block; float: left` and fixed widths, but then you lose the general table functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<tr>
<td colspan = "2">A1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A2</td><td>A3</td>
</tr>
```

I presume your A's, B's, etc. are really an array, so that you can run a loop to produce your rows.  If you need a more generalized way to split things, you can keep a counter of how many cells you have in a given row, and go to the next row based on the modulus of your counter.  For example, if you want to split the row after each five elements

```
<cfset i = 0>
  <cfloop array = #myarray# index = "col">
<tr>
<cfset i = i + 1>
<cfset j = i%5>  <!---this is i mod 5 --->
<td>#col# (or whatever is based on col) </td> 
<cfif j EQ 0>
</tr>
<tr>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I realize this is probably too late for your immediate problem, but might help someone else.

Comment: Kind of changes the meaning of the data, which I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps read up on the flexible box (flexbox) layout stuff in CSS3:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not sure how these styles apply to tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to change the browser's table rendering algorithm to do this. There is no means of achieving this with CSS *that will work with your exact table structure*.

You've identified that a table is the best layout for your information, and that's your call. The exact structure of the data in that table is your call too, as long as it is logically valid.

That being said, I do question the intent being expressed here. If you are trying to imply visually that the two cells are 'really' one cell, then you should consider making that relationship explicit if possible, probably with th's and rowspan. Why would you imply something meaningful about that relationship to visual agents, but not to non-visual agents?

I would be reevaluating my cell structure at this point if it were me. Once you've committed to a table structure, you are bound by more specific semantic rules. Yes, presentation and semantics are technically separate. But not when you're trying to visually express the opposite of your tag semantics; and not when something meaningful is being expressed visually that is not apparent non-visually.